# разница получения элементов между чистым js и jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

В footer.php подключен файл

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/js/loadmore.js"></script>
```

в файле loadmore.js я хочу получить элемент

```
var element = document.getElementById('#interview');
```

переменная element равна null
Вот блок заготовки, в которой находится этот id

```
<div class="grid_24 alpha omega pb40 interviews" id='interview' >

                <?php
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 16, 'category_name' => 'interviews,statements,speeches', 'paged'=>$paged ) );
                   while ( $query->have_posts() ) {$query->the_post();

                    get_template_part( 'template-post-news', get_post_format() );

                                 } ?>
                </div>
```

Если вызывать через jQuery  $elem = $('#interview') то этот элемент выводится. Но мне нужны методы , которые не запускаются с jQuery. Помогите понять, почему я не могу получить элемент через чистый js

Comment: `var ...getElementById('#interview');` => `var ...getElementById('interview');`

Comment: спасибо, извините за глупый вопрос, это все невнимательность

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Либо так:

```
var element = document.getElementById('interview');
```

Или:

```
var element = document.querySelector('#interview');
```

Comment: спасибо , все работает)

Comment: @АлександрРодин тогда можете отметить ответ верным (галочка под ответом) и поднять рейтинг вверх)

Comment: не прохожу по минимальному рейтингу, чтоб оценить ответ)

Comment: Ладно, я плюсанул за автора вопроса )